# Javascript / Openlayers for loop not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, openlayers

I'm creating a map with OpenLayers and am having trouble getting features to appear.

I want to take an array, and assign each coordinate it's own marker.  This is the relevant code (full code at bottom of post):

```
                var npctowns = [
                    [ 533, mapy-966 ],
                    [ 833, mapy-1766 ],
                    [ 2000, mapy-500 ],
                    [ 1500, mapy-1700 ]

                ];
                for (var i = 0; i < npctowns.length; i++) {

                    var lon = npctowns[i][0];
                    var lat = npctowns[i][0];

                    var npcTownIcons = new ol.Feature({
                        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([lon,lat])
                    });
                    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                        image: new ol.style.Icon ({
                        anchor: [0, 0],
                        anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                        opacity: 1,
                        src: 'assets/img/icons/Town.gif'
                        })
                    });
                    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                        features: [npcTownIcons]
                        });
                    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        source: vectorSource
                        });

                };
```

I think I am running into a problem not assigning the feature variable dynamically?  But not sure how to fix it!  Any help is really appreciated!

Full map code on jsfiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/dhaurhvj/

Comment: if the answer is not helping, point to the problems. If it does, please accept it.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks hi and thanks for the reply!  haven't had a chance to test it out just yet, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `vectorLayer` outside the `for` loop, so the map initialization can access that `vectorLayer`. 
Then You actually need to add those features to the layer (because it was created before).

I think the code should look like this:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({features: [[]]});
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon ({
        anchor: [0, 0],
        anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
        opacity: 1,
        src: 'assets/img/icons/Town.gif'
    })
});
for (var i = 0; i < npctowns.length; i++) {                         
    var lon = npctowns[i][0];
    var lat = npctowns[i][0];

    var newIcon = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([lon,lat])
    });

    newIcon.setStyle(iconStyle);
    vectorSource.addFeature(newIcon);
};
```

You can also populate an Array with those (`newIcon`) features and initialize vectorLayer after the loop and pass that array to it.